# Imagemagic - How to get mirror image

Tags: php, imagemagick

How we can  create mirror image using imagemagic in php?

Here is the code i have used:

```
$output_h       = 1200;
$output_w       = 1200;
$image_size     = 600;
$src        = './images/upload/'.$image;
$output_morror  = './images/upload/mirror_'.$filename[0].'.png';

//Mirror
exec('convert '.$src.' -resize '.$image_size.' \( -clone 0 -flip \) -append +write mpr:sometile  +delete -size '.$output_w.'x'.$output_h.' tile:mpr:sometile '.$output_morror);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you assumed horizontal mirror.

```
<?php

// unix paths are used here
$original_image_path = '/path/to/original/image.jpg';
$mirrored_image_path = '/path/to/mirrored/image.jpg';

$image = new \Imagick($original_image_path);
$image->flopimage();
$image->writeImage($mirrored_image_path);
```

See [official documentation of ImageMagic extension](http://www.php.net/manual/book.imagick.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/csh -f

#
# Mirror image vertically and horizontally  
#
#  Example:
#   ./mirror-tile.csh 'inImage' 'outImage'
#

if ($#argv != 2)  then
   echo "Mirror Tile input image"
   echo "   ./mirror-tile.csh 'inImage' 'outImage'"
   exit
endif

set inImage="$1"
set outImage="$2"

magick "$inImage" -background transparent -extent 200% \( +clone -flip \) -composite \( +clone -flop \) -composite "$outImage"
```